# Can someone tell me why I keep getting error "unexpected non-void return value in void function"

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I get an error when trying to return a true or false Bool value... Can someone help ? I was trying to check if user exists in Firebase database.

```
    func checkIfUserExists(email: String) -> Bool{

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

            switch email {
            case dictionary["email"] as! String!:
                return true
                break
            default:
                return false
                break
            }
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it this way

```
func checkIfUserExists(email: String, results:(exists:Bool)->Void){
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

            switch email {
            case dictionary["email"] as! String!:
                results(true)
                break
            default:
                results(false)
                break
            }
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

The function can be called like this

```
checkIfUserExists(email: "some email", results:{ exists
     if exists {
       //do something 
     }
     else{
       // user do not exist... do something   
     }
})
```

@ohr answer should be the acepted one, this is only a clarification

Comment: success ? return true : return false
this line gives me an error expected expression after '?' in ternary ecpression

Comment: This is completely wrong, it will return always `false`. Simple rule: **You cannot return something from an asynchronous task in a function's return parameter**

Comment: sorry for that huge mistake :D now it is reformulated with a working example.

Comment: when I try to use it checkIfUserExists it says that Expected declaration ?

Comment: I have eddited my answer to remove an extra ")" that was added accidentally

Answer (score 2):

Your return is inside a closure, not your function. What comes to mind is you could return a closure in your function like this

```
func checkIfUserExists(email: String, completion:(success:Bool) -> ())
```

And then once your FIRDatabase closure ends instead of return true or false you

```
completion(success:true) // or false
```

And use it like this.

```
checkIfUserExists("email@mail.com") { (success) in
    if success
    {
        // Email found
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

This [link](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/) could be helpful

Comment: hmm... but I only need one parameter in function 'email' and i want to return true or false according on switch

Comment: And I would also mention, that break calls are not needed in cases, because switch cases don't have implicit fallthrough.

Comment: @Moonwalker4z, call the function with your email, then hit enter on the completion block to auto generate code.

Comment: @ohr ok and what do i writhe in the code and in completion ?

Comment: @ohr ok but how do I get success property ?

Comment: You declared it in your closure.

Comment: @ohr Can you add that to your answer I would help a lot :)